# Display Crystal Report Viewer in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I'm having some trouble in CrystalReport ASP.NET.

I'm creating a `DataSet` in ASP.NET and I want to export it to `CrystalReport.rpt` using ADO.NET(xml). But it fails. When I make a new connection and put an attribute column in the report, the `Main Report Viewer` in Crystal Report shows the wrong result. I compile the sql query in `Oraclesqldevelop`, the result is fine and doesn't have any problems. I want to click a button and show the report.

This is my code :

```
protected void btnsumbit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblerror.Text = "";
    if (txtdari.Text == "" || txtdari.Text == null || txtsampai.Text == "" || txtsampai.Text == null)
    {
        lblerror.Text = "Tanggal Harus Diisi !!!";
    }
    else 
    {
        DateTime dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(txtdari.Text);
        DateTime dt2 = Convert.ToDateTime(txtsampai.Text);
        if (dt1.Date > dt2.Date)
        {
            lblerror.Text = "Format Tanggal yang Dimasukkan Salah !!!";
        }
        else 
        {
            OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = connectionstring;
            conn.Open();
            string sql = "SELECT c.SUB_DISTRIBUTOR , c.MID  , c.REKNO , b.ID, b.TERMINAL_ID , b.TANGGAL , b.KETERANGAN , b.DEBIT , b.KREDIT , b.SALDO , b.REFF_NO,b.PRODUK,b.NO_PELANGGAN, b.SN_ID , b.STATUS from MERCHANT c JOIN DAILY b  ON (b.REKENING_NO = c.REKNO) where TANGGAL between TO_DATE('"+txtdari.Text+"','mm-dd-yyyy') AND TO_DATE('"+txtsampai.Text+"','mm-dd-yyyy')";
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn);
            OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            da.Dispose();

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            ds.WriteXmlSchema("C:\\Users\\Henz\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\LPI\\LPI\\Files\\Sample.xml");
            conn.Close();

            Response.Redirect("plot.aspx");
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As your description, I can understand that there is not any error happened. The main issue is your result is not like your expectation. So I think you should check again Parameter of your command. Please try with below code :

```
DateTime dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(txtdari.Text);
DateTime dt2 = Convert.ToDateTime(txtsampai.Text);

////////ARI DATE/////////
OracleParameter fromDateParameter = new OracleParameter();
fromDateParameter.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Date;
fromDateParameter.Value = dt1;

////////SAMPAI DATE/////////
OracleParameter toDateParameter = new OracleParameter();
toDateParameter.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Date;
toDateParameter.Value = dt2;


this.oracleDataAdapter4.SelectCommand = new OracleCommand("SELECT c.SUB_DISTRIBUTOR , c.MID  , c.REKNO , b.ID, b.TERMINAL_ID , b.TANGGAL, b.KETERANGAN , b.DEBIT , b.KREDIT , b.SALDO , b.REFF_NO,b.PRODUK,b.NO_PELANGGAN,   b.SN_ID , b.STATUS from MERCHANT c JOIN DAILY b  ON (b.REKENING_NO = c.REKNO) where TANGGAL BETWEEN :fromDateParameter AND :fromDateParameter)”, conn);
OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);


da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(fromDateParameter);           
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(toDateParameter);  
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
```